# define two dimensional array in c# with string indexes

Tags: c#, arrays, list

How can I define something like this in c#:

```
list["alpha","beta"] = value;
```

And I want to access values such as dictionary:

```
var item = list["alpha","beta"];
```

Comment: there is no such type in .NET Framework. you need to implement your own type to suit your needs.

Comment: I think you should define a Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>, and then you can access as dict[key1[key2]].. does it help?

Comment: This question is possibly a duplicate, but not of the chosen question. This question is asking for a multi-key dictionary, not a multi-value dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is not a 2d array, but a dictionary of dictionaries. 
See documentation for dictionaries [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

You'll then write myDic[ "outerDicKey" ][ "innerDicKey" ] to retrieve a value.

Comment: Another way would be to inherit from `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and use a tuple as the key for the base dictionary class, and adding the requisite `this[string key1, string key2]` and corresponding Add, Remove, ContainsKey, etc. ie. `public class DualKeyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<Tuple<TKey, TKey>, TValue> { ... }`

Comment: Indeed. Caveat: tuple is .NET 4 only.

Answer (score 1):

Implement your type that aggregate Dictionary:

```
class Test
{
    private struct Key
    {
        public string Key1 { get; set; }

        public string Key2 { get; set; }

        public Key(string key1, string key2) 
            : this()
        {
            Key1 = key1;
            Key2 = key2;
        }
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<Key, object> _dictionary = new Dictionary<Key, object>();

    public object this[string key1, string key2]
    {
        get { return _dictionary[new Key(key1, key2)]; }
        set { _dictionary[new Key(key1, key2)] = value; }
    }
}
```